# Image source path is converting into blop instead of real path in tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I have an issue with latest tinyMCE editor, whenever I try to select and edit the image, it's source is converting into blob path like this.

blob:http://localhost/87d42e34-9961-412c-914b-dc6a77ab68e0

Did anyone of you face this issue or resolved... ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit images using the TinyMCE Image Tools you will get one of these encoded images - that is how the Image Tools work.

What you can then do is configure TinyMCE to upload this image and you can store that image as you see fit for your application.

The basic process is that TinyMCE will create a separate HTTP POST for each image that you modify with the image editor. It will send that image to a URL of your choosing (via HTTP POST) based on the setting of the `images_upload_url` option in your init.

The image handler at the URL referenced in the `images_upload_url` (which you have to create) has to do whatever needs to be done to "store" the image in your application. That could mean something like:

- Store the item in a folder on your web server
- Store the item in a database
- Store the item in an asset management system

...regardless of where you choose to store the image your image handler needs to return a single line of JSON telling TinyMCE the new location of the image. As referenced in the TinyMCE documentation this might look like:

```
{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }
```

TinyMCE will then update the image's src attribute to the value you return. If you use the `images_upload_base_path` setting in the init that will be prepended to the returned location. The TinyMCE page has more details on all of this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

The net here is that the Image tools will create one of these encoded images whenever you edit an image.  TinyMCE knows when an embedded image exists in your content but it can't possibly know what to do with that image in the context of your application so that job (the "image handler") is something you must create.